# IOS 5: AVAudioPlayer console log

Tags: objective-c, ios5, avaudioplayer, avplayer

Hi I got some console log on execution of following code in iOS 5. Anything wrong with code? how can I avoid this log?

Code:

```
     NSURL* tapSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                  pathForResource:@"tap"
                                                  ofType:@"m4a"]];

     AVAudioPlayer *mClickSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: tapSound error: nil];
    [mClickSound prepareToPlay];
    mClickSound.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [mClickSound setVolume: 1.0f];

    [mClickSound play];
```

### Console Log:

> Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>
>   Expected in:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2011-12-22 11:28:16.615 iCarrom Fun[1890:1db03] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

---

Answer (score 0):

Expected references from the Security.framework are missing... perhaps you imported an old version of security.framework to a newer app made in a  newer version of xCode? Download the newest frameworks and use those after cleaning your project.